# Express js: Google Oauth Api returns "Moved Temporarily"

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth

I'm trying to use google oauth api to login to my website with. I'm using HTTP requests, but I get a 302 http code(redirection/Moved Temporarily), and I'm not sure what to do and how to do it. I guess I should make another http request with the new location but I don't know how to get it.

Here is the core I'm using:

```
var redirectUri = encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:3000/user/login/oauth2"); 
var clientId = "322263763991.apps.googleusercontent.com";
var clientSecret = "********************";

var dataPath    = "/o/oauth2/token"
                            + "?code="                  + cod 
                            + "&client_id="         + clientId 
                            + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret 
                            + "&redirect_uri="  + redirectUri 
                            + "&grant_type=authorization_code";

var options = {
      host: 'accounts.google.com',
      path: dataPath,
      method: 'POST'
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

      console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('X_BODY: ' + chunk);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    req.write('data\n');
    req.write('data\n');
    req.end();
```

Comment: Perhaps not a direct answer, but have you considered using Passport? It has a strategy for authenticating using Google ([here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth)). FWIW: isn't the 302 generated by Google to redirect you to `redirect_uri`?

Comment: I'm making this comment to show you not only robertklep would use Passport, but I would too. I think almost everyone would. It's really painless to get OAuth running with it.